# fizzbuzz in haskell?

Tags: haskell, fizzbuzz

I'm trying to write 'fizzbuzz' in haskell using list comprehensions.

Why doesn't the following work, and how should it be?

```
[ if x `mod` 5 == 0 then "BUZZFIZZ"
  if x `mod` 3 == 0 then "BUZZ" 
  if x `mod` 4 == 0 then "FIZZ" | x <- [1..20], 
    x `mod` 3 == 0, 
    x `mod` 4 == 0, 
    x `mod` 5 == 0 ]
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run that?

Comment: it whinges because there's no 'else' for each 'if'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, you're missing the `else` parts of your `if` expressions. In Haskell, `if` is an expression, not a statement, so the `else` part is mandatory.

Secondly, the list comprehension only produces any values if *all* the guard expressions evaluate to `True`. There is no number between 1 and 20 that is 0 modulo 3, 4, and 5, so you'll get no results. You'll want to use `||` (logical OR) to combine them instead.

Third, most definitions of FizzBuzz want you to return the number itself if it does not meet any of the other conditions. In that case, you'll want to use `show` to convert the number to a `String`.

Answer (score 41):

This isn't valid Haskell.  The `else` branch is not optional in `if ... then ... else`.  Rather than using `if`, this seems like a good opportunity to use a `case` statement.

```
case (x `rem` 3, x `rem` 5) of
  (0,0) -> "fizzbuzz"
  (0,_) -> "fizz"
  (_,0) -> "buzz"
  _     -> show x
```

This snippet will work for a traditional "fizzbuzz"; your code seems to be slightly different.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another version that can be extended to an arbitrary number of substitutions:

```
fizzbuzz' :: [(Integer, String)] -> Integer -> String
fizzbuzz' ss n = foldl (\str (num, subst) -> if n `mod` num == 0 then str ++ subst else str ++ "") "" ss

fizzbuzz :: [(Integer, String)] -> Integer -> String
fizzbuzz ss n = if null str then show n else str
  where str = fizzbuzz' ss n
```

You could inline `fizzbuzz'` in the `where` clause of `fizzbuzz`, but I found a separate function easier for testing.

You can run it like this:

```
λ> mapM_ putStrLn $ map (fizzbuzz [(3, "fizz"), (5, "buzz")]) [9..15]
fizz
buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizzbuzz
```

Or with extra substitutions:

```
λ> mapM_ putStrLn $ map (fizzbuzz [(3, "fizz"), (5, "buzz"), (7, "dazz")]) [19..24]
19
buzz
fizzdazz
22
23
fizz
```

Answer (score 3):

In general, it helps if you give the error as well, not just the code.

But in this case, the problem is that every `if` needs an `else` clause. Keep in mind that an `if` statement is just an expression, so both branches must return a value of an appropriate type.

You've got several bugs in the code, by the way, but that's the only compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a response to the traditional FizzBuzz problem using list comprehension + guards.

```
fizzbuzz = [fb x| x <- [1..100]]
    where fb y
        | y `mod` 15 == 0 = "FizzBuzz"
        | y `mod` 3  == 0 = "Fizz"
        | y `mod` 5  == 0 = "Buzz"
        | otherwise  = show y
```

Or alternatively don't be afraid to move `where` clause into separate succinct function for evaluating `x` then call that function from your list comprehension. Its better to build on small concise functions than trying to solve it in one more complex function. e.g.

```
fizzval x
    | x `mod` 15 == 0 = "FizzBuzz"
    | x `mod` 3  == 0 = "Fizz"
    | x `mod` 5  == 0 = "Buzz"
    | otherwise  = show x

fizzbuzz = [fizzval x| x <- [1..100]]
```

Comment: I tried running that with ghci: `fizzbuzz.hs:3:9: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
`

Answer (score 3):

With the help of some judicious currying, Calvin Bottoms did it in 77 characters.

http://freshbrewedcode.com/calvinbottoms/2012/02/25/fizzbuzz-in-haskell/

```
[max(show x)(concat[n|(f,n)<-[(3,"Fizz"),(5,"Buzz")],mod x f==0])|x<-[1..25]]
```

Answer (score 2):

[The Monad Reader](https://themonadreader.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/fizzbuzz.pdf) contains a solution as well as many valuable insights and some more fun exercises. The solution is copied here for those who just want to see it.

```
fizzbuzz :: Int -> String
fizzbuzz n = (test 3 "fizz" . test 5 "buzz") id (show n)
    where test d s x | n `mod` d == 0 = const (s ++ x "")
                     | otherwise      = x
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no x that fullfills the condition to be divisible by 3, 4 and 5 in the range 1..20.

Therefore, you would get an empty list if the example were syntactically correct, which it is not.